# Show the following inequality holds. (with vector and dot product)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider a sequence of vector $s_1, s_2, ..., s_t$, a sequence of vector $x_1, x_2, ..., x_t$, a costant $a$ belonging to $R$ and the following iterative equation:

$$
x_{t+1} = x_t - a\cdot s_t\qquad\text{and}\qquad x_1 = 0.
$$
Show the following inequality:
$$
\sum_{t=1}^T ((x_t - x) * s_t) \le  \frac{\|x\|^2}{2a} + \frac a2\cdot\sum_{t=1}^T ||s_t||^2.
$$
holds for any x belonging to $R^d$

Comment: Why are you writing * for the dot product?  Welcome to MSE. Please show us what you've tried and where you've gotten stuck. Don't just post what sure look like homework problems to us. Moreover, what you've written several times doesn't make sense. I guess the original sequence is $\{s_t: 1\le t\le T\}$? You've used $t$ as a fixed number and also as a dummy variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity I assume $a=1$. Also, I replace $t$ by $n$ and $T$ by $N$ and denote $y_n = s_n$ (because I don't like $s$ for vectors). First of all, it is clear that $x_{n+1} = -\sum_{k=1}^ny_k$.

Now, let $x\in\mathbb R^d$ be arbitrary. We set $y_{N+1} := x$. Then the LHS of your inequality is
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=2}^Nx_ny_n - \sum_{n=1}^Nxy_n
&= -\sum_{n=2}^N\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}y_k\right)y_n - \sum_{n=1}^Ny_{N+1}y_n\\
&= -\left(\sum_{n=2}^N\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}y_ky_n +\sum_{k=1}^Ny_ky_{N+1}\right) = -\sum_{n=2}^{N+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}y_ky_n.
\end{align*}
Hence, the inequality to show is
$$
-\sum_{n=2}^{N+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}y_ky_n\,\le\,\frac 12\sum_{n=1}^{N+1}\|y_n\|^2.
$$
Equivalently,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{N+1}\|y_n\|^2 + 2\sum_{n=2}^{N+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}y_ky_n\,\ge\,0.
$$
But the LHS of this inequality just coincides with
$$
\left\|\sum_{n=1}^{N+1}y_n\right\|^2,
$$
which of course is non-negative.

Comment: why the first sum start from 2? @amsmath

Comment: Because $x_1=0$.